# Is the first order symbolic statement $\forall x (x \in M \land \phi(x) )$ always false?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I recently learned the correct ways of using the universal and existential quantifiers in the context of being in a set and exhibiting a particular property...specifically:

$\forall x \in M, \phi (x) \iff \forall x \big( x \in M \rightarrow \phi(x) \big)$

$\exists x \in M, \phi(x) \iff \exists x \big (x \in M \land \phi(x) \big )$

However, I also learned that, although it would rarely have any purposeful usage, the statement $\exists x \big (x \in M \rightarrow \phi(x) \big )$ is valid.

My question is as follows:

Is the first order symbolic statement $\forall x (x \in M \land \phi(x) )$ ***always false?***

My thinking is that it depends on the axiomatic framework you are working in. The only time this statement could be true is if one's model permits a universal set (I think). Therefore, in Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory, where universal sets are disallowed, this statement is always false.

Is this the correct thinking?

Comment: Yes. The statement $\forall x\,(x\in M\land\phi(x))$ says that everything is an element of $M$ and everything satisfies $\phi$. (Universal quantifiers distribute over $\land$.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you! For clarification, though, the issue with this statement is not because of $\phi(x)$; rather, it is with $x \in M$. If $\phi(x)$ was the statement, "is a set", then certainly, it would be true for every object (in the context of ZFC). The lone issue is with $x \in M$. Right?

Comment: @S.Cramer In a pure set theory (i.e. one in which all objects are sets), $x=x$ is an equivalent predicate to 'x is a set' so there's really no reason to explicitly have the latter (though you will have one for theories with atoms or classes). Yes, pretty much the lone issue is $x\in M$ and your thinking is largely correct. One could find things to quibble about: if empty universes are possible, any universal sentence is true, but then $M$ is free so is this really a sentence? But by any large, yes the issue is whether $M$ can be universal.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen lovely. Cheers~